# Back bar button showing a white box

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, back, backbarbuttonitem

I have a SwiftUI project but it shows a big white box with the back bar button.

Does anyone know how to fix it (Xcode version 12.5)?

Image:

[image]

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var show = false
    @State var status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
    
    var body: some View{
        
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                
                if self.status{
                    
                    Homescreen()
                }
                else{
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: SignUp(show: self.$show), isActive: self.$show) {
                            
                            Text("")
                        }
                        .hidden()
                        
                        Login(show: self.$show)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
                    
                    self.status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Homescreen : View {
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            Text("Logged successfully")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            Button(action: {
                
                try! Auth.auth().signOut()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                
            }) {
                
                Text("Log out")
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 25)
        }
    }
}

struct Login : View {
    
    @State var color = Color.black.opacity(0.7)
    @State var email = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var visible = false
    @Binding var show : Bool
    @State var alert = false
    @State var error = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        
        ZStack{
            
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                
                GeometryReader{_ in
                    
                    VStack{
                        
                        
                        Text("Log in to your account")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding(.top, 35)
                        
                        TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .padding()
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.email != "" ? Color("Color.Color") : self.color,lineWidth: 2))
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            
                            VStack{
                                
                                if self.visible{
                                    
                                    TextField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                                else{
                                    
                                    SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                self.visible.toggle()
                                
                            }) {
                                
                                Image(systemName: self.visible ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.pass != "" ? Color("Color") : self.color,lineWidth: 2))
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        
                        HStack{
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                self.reset()
                                
                            }) {
                                
                                Text("Forget password")
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            self.verify()
                            
                        }) {
                            
                            Text("Log in")
                                .padding(.vertical)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
                        }
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.show.toggle()
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Text("Register")
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .frame(width:
                            UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
                }
                .background(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 400)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            }
            
            if self.alert{
                
                ErrorView(alert: self.$alert, error: self.$error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func verify(){
        
        if self.email != "" && self.pass != ""{
            
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
                
                print("success")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
            }
        }
        else{
            
            self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func reset(){
        
        if self.email != ""{
            
            Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.email) { (err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
                
                self.error = "RESET"
                self.alert.toggle()
            }
        }
        else{
            
            self.error = "Email Id is empty"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct SignUp : View {
    
    @State var color = Color.black.opacity(0.7)
    @State var email = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var repass = ""
    @State var visible = false
    @State var revisible = false
    @Binding var show : Bool
    @State var alert = false
    @State var error = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        
        ZStack{
            
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                
                GeometryReader{_ in
                    
                    VStack{
                        
                        Text("Register your account")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding(.top, 35)
                        
                        TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .padding()
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.email != "" ? Color("Color") : self.color,lineWidth: 2))
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            
                            VStack{
                                
                                if self.visible{
                                    
                                    TextField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                                else{
                                    
                                    SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                self.visible.toggle()
                                
                            }) {
                                
                                Image(systemName: self.visible ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.pass != "" ? Color("Color") : self.color,lineWidth: 2))
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            
                            VStack{
                                
                                if self.revisible{
                                    
                                    TextField("Re-enter", text: self.$repass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                                else{
                                    
                                    SecureField("Re-enter", text: self.$repass)
                                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                self.revisible.toggle()
                                
                            }) {
                                
                                Image(systemName: self.revisible ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.repass != "" ? Color("Color") : self.color,lineWidth: 2))
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            self.register()
                        }) {
                            
                            Text("Register")
                                .padding(.vertical)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
                        }
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.top, 25)
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 25)
               
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.show.toggle()
                    
                }) {
                    
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
            if self.alert{
                
                ErrorView(alert: self.$alert, error: self.$error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func register(){
        
        if self.email != ""{
            
            if self.pass == self.repass{
                
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                    
                    if err != nil{
                        
                        self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                        self.alert.toggle()
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print("success")
                    
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                }
            }
            else{
                
                self.error = "Password mismatch"
                self.alert.toggle()
            }
        }
        else{
            
            self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
}


struct ErrorView : View {
    
    @State var color = Color.black.opacity(0.7)
    @Binding var alert : Bool
    @Binding var error : String
    
    var body: some View{
        
        GeometryReader{_ in
            
            VStack{
                
                HStack{
                    
                    Text(self.error == "RESET" ? "Message" : "Error")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                
                Text(self.error == "RESET" ? "Password reset link has been sent successfully" : self.error)
                .padding(.top)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Text(self.error == "RESET" ? "Ok" : "Cancel")
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120)
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 25)
                
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 25)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.35).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`.navigationTitle(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationtitle(_:)-avgj) instead.

First **remove** this code:

```
Text("Register your account")
    .font(.title)
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .padding(.top, 35)
```

And then somewhere else in this view, for example on the `TextField` just below, add the modifier:

```
.navigationTitle("Register your account")
```

Result:

[image]